Unity camera NullReferenceException
I am new to Unity so I am not sure what is going on.  I am trying to draw lines with some mouse clicks.  However, I keep getting a NullReferenceException on my camera.  I'm attempting to utilize a command pattern in my environment. If my line command is NOT being called through the invoker.  It runs fine.  If its being called through the invoker, i get the null reference on the camera.  I am sure I am making a simple mistake somewhere
Here's my invoker class CommandInvoker.cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CommandInvoker : MonoBehaviour
{
    static Queue<ICommand> CommandBuffer;

    private void Awake()
    {
        CommandBuffer = new Queue<ICommand>();
    }

    public static void AddCommand(ICommand command)
    {
        CommandBuffer.Enqueue(command);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(CommandBuffer.Count > 0)
        {
            ICommand c = CommandBuffer.Dequeue();
            if(c != null)
            {
                c.Execute();
            }
        }
    }
}

Here is my DrawLineCommand.cs
using UnityEngine;

public class DrawLineCommand : ICommand
{
    public Line MyLine;

    public DrawLineCommand()
    {
        Debug.Log("Draw Line Command firing");
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        Debug.Log("We are firing a line command");        
        MyLine.InitLine();
    }
}

and here is my Line.cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

public class Line : MonoBehaviour
{
    private LineRenderer _lRenderer;
    private List<Vector3> _Vertices = new List<Vector3>();
    public Material material;


    private void Start()
    {
        this.InitLine();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        try
        {
            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
            {
            
                Ray CamRay = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
                RaycastHit hit;

                if (Physics.Raycast(CamRay, out hit))
                {
                    if (hit.transform.GetComponent<Renderer>().name == "MyGround")
                    {
                        EditorUtility.DisplayDialog("Some Title", "This is my message", "are we ok?");

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception Ex)
        {
            throw new System.Exception(Ex.Message);
        }
    }

    public void InitLine()
    {
        this._lRenderer = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();

        this._lRenderer.positionCount = 0;
        this._lRenderer.startWidth = 0.15f;
        this._lRenderer.endWidth = 0.15f;
        this._lRenderer.useWorldSpace = true;
        this._lRenderer.numCapVertices = 50;
    }
}


Just a thought, try moving the initialization of the command buffer to the declaration line instead of Awake.  Since it is static, the object may not exist or accessed before assignment.
